# Canadian crossing back from the USA

Tags: usa, canada, overstaying

what is the best way to enter back to Canada from the USA when I do not want a stamp on my passport and I have an expired enhanced drivers licence?

i have over stayed my time in the USA and i am scared to get banned.

Comment: What is your nationality? What type of visa were you on in the U.S.? And is there any relation of your question to the Candian Rockies?

Comment: @mts what do the Rockies have to do with anything?

Comment: @phoog canadian-rockies was the first and only tag before I edited so there is an off-chance it might be related to the Q.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't give advice on how to break the law or how to escape the consequences of breaking the law.

Comment: @mts the asker has an enhanced driver's license and we can deduce that he or she is not a US citizen, so the only other option is Canadian.

Answer (score 3):

Pick any crossing. The US has no exit immigration control, so you will only go through Canadian entry Immigration control

Are you a Canadian permanent resident? If so just use your permanent resident Card.

If not, foreign passport are stamped. Just get a new one if this is an issue.

Comment: I don't think that's the question.  As I read it, OP's concern is that Canadian immigration will stamp their passport, and that on their next attempt to enter the US, US immigration will deduce from the dates that OP had overstayed.

Comment: @NateEldredge Does Canada stamp Canadians' passports?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Good question.  The US stamps US citizens' passports on entry, in at least some circumstances.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't think the US usually stamps US passports at the Canadian land border.  I'll check mine later.

Comment: The US may stamp US passports depending on the officer. Especially at land borders, and at Airports when using APC kiosks, they increasingly don't, and even if you see them trying you can easily ask them not to

Comment: @NateEldredge: They would deduce only if they have records of when he entered. But if they have records of when he entered, and he doesn't have an exit record, they will assume the worst case, that he continued to stay until the latest possible time, unless he proves otherwise.